# Does django-allauth provide a simple email/password method to replace the username/password method of django

Tags: django-registration, django-allauth

Does django-allauth provide a basic way of using email/password instead of using the default username/password of Django? (without the need of having a social account)

On this tutorial, http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/#Now_we_can_login_using_Django_or_Facebook, after he set up "Facebook", you see that the basic method is still by username.

[django-registration-email](https://github.com/bitmazk/django-registration-email) has been discontinued due to the give-up of django-registration and  they mention to look at django-allauth but I do not see whether you can replace the default django username/password method with only an email/password like this app was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I'm doing exactly what you asked and it works. I use Allauth without using social account and login with email/password.

The settings for what you want are:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

The username is still internally created but it can be totally transparent to the user.

Comment: oh ok so it supports that as well. I thought it was just about social accounts and was using the default django way of creating an account , i.e. with a username.
Does it include by default the feature of sending an email to confirm it? If yes, what happens if I register with Facebook only for example? I am a bit confused of the flow mixing the basic method and the social account method. 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it includes sending an e-mail to confirm the address, and I'm using it.  Since I'm not using any social login, I don't know what happens when you register with Facebook. If this answered your question, please accept and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: You can quickly test the facebook login with this example: https://github.com/aellerton/demo-allauth-bootstrap